# Empty `IMG_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS` folders in `DCIM`: What are they there for?

Tags: photos, file-management

I have empty `IMG_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS` folders in my `DCIM` folder, each of them having a corresponding `IMG_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.jpg` photo (but there are some photos that don't have an associated folder). What are those there for and can I safely delete them?

Comment: My guess is that these folders are perhaps used to hold an edit/undo history when a photo is edited? It's probably dependent on your phone/camera app?